# How can I run multiple eclipse launch files sequentially?

Tags: eclipse

Here's an example scenario

I have three launch files named A, B, C.
I want B to run after A finishes and C to run after B finishes.

Currently if I run A which takes a lot of time and run B immediately afterwards B starts executing in parallel with A.

Please help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run Configurations -> Launch Group.

There you can add launch configurations and order them too!
Found it [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_run_dbg_launch_group.htm)

For sequentially running remember to select Post launch action: Wait until terminated

Comment: Interesting. Needs the CDT, though.

Comment: I thought that this will do the job but I cannot seem to find any way to insert parameters ...

Comment: Perfect, this is just what I needed. I don't think it still requires CDT, seems to be included in newer versions of Eclipse: see https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdebug_launch_groups.htm

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest creating a script (bash/Powershell/Ant/whatever) and setting up a single *External Run Configuration* for that.

Simply call A, when it finishes run B and C with forking.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the projects into [modules](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) and create a parent POM which executes the build in order.

By using the `mvn install -pl :A`, you can still build each module individually or `mvn install -rf :B` to build B and C in order (I'm using the command line notation, in Eclipse, you can set these using the Maven launch editor).

Comment: I agree this is a valid answer for running three pom modules consecutively. I literally mean to run the configurations sequentially, this solution is pom only :(

Comment: It's not bad at all. It's just a pom only solution. And also there are cases where I can't fit it. Like modules A,B,C are children of parent module P which has children A,B,C,D,E,F,G.... All refer P as parent. Now if you create another parent P1 for A,B,C then all pom files of A,B,C need to be changed!

Comment: You can use a profile for this: Instead of creating another POM, create a profile which has a only a subset of `<module>` elements. Or you can use `-pl :A,:B,:C` to build A,B and C in this order.

Comment: it still remains pom only solution. I have found the solution. Updated answer. Thank you for your valuable time :)